# How to protect against substringFromIndex crash?

Tags: objective-c

So in my app I get some dynamic text, which I need to extract a certain part of the text out and display it. The part I need from the string can be in a few places. So I wrote this bit of code to handle it:

```
-(NSString *)getEftPaymentReference
{

    NSRange orderNoteStringRange;
    NSRange endOfRangeForString;

    NSString *string;
    NSString *originalString;


    if (![self.orderPayment.orderPaymentNote hasPrefix:@"ref"]){

                /* Convert the string into plain text */
                originalString = [[self.orderPayment.orderPaymentNote stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText] stringByDecodingHTMLEntities];

                /* Get the range before the "at" */
                orderNoteStringRange = [originalString rangeOfString:@"at"]; // Reference code before  this bit

                /* Create a new string with this range */
                string = [originalString substringToIndex:orderNoteStringRange.location];

                /* Get the range after "reference" */
                endOfRangeForString = [string rangeOfString:@"reference" ]; //Reference code after this bit

                /* Returned string now has just the code eg: $FHSR for the reference */
                string = [string substringFromIndex:endOfRangeForString.location + 10]; //10 added to cover the word "reverence" + white space before the code;

    }else {

                /* Convert the string into plain text */
                originalString = [[self.orderPayment.orderPaymentNote stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText] stringByDecodingHTMLEntities];

                /* Get the range after "ref." */
                orderNoteStringRange = [originalString rangeOfString:@"ref."]; // Reference code before  this bit

                /* Create a new string with this range */
                string = [originalString substringFromIndex:orderNoteStringRange.location + 5];

    }

    return string;
}
```

However I am seeing crashes from my users with the following error:

> ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFString substringFromIndex:]: Index 9223372036854775817 out of bounds; string length 46'

Now I am not sure why the crash is happening and it doesn't happen often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious bogus value `9223372036854775817` is `NSNotFound` + 10. So, this part:

```
            endOfRangeForString = [string rangeOfString:@"reference" ]; //Reference code after this bit
```

has returned an `NSRange` whose `location` field is `NSNotFound`. The string `@"reference"` is not within `string` at that point.

You must always check the result from methods like this. Do not assume that a string contains what you think it "must".

By the way, this sort of task is the sort of thing that `NSScanner` would be good at.

Comment: Thank you. How do I check against that before? You mentioned NSScanner... I'll go read the docs to see what the class can do. Thank you.

Comment: When a method returns an `NSRange`, you need to do something like `if (range.location == NSNotFound) { /* handle failure to find what you were looking for */ } else { /* handle success finding what you were looking for */ }`.

Comment: Fantastic. I see you're correct in that NSScanner looks to be the more appropriate abstract class for this type of task. Thanks for the help, it's enough to get me started on what I need to do to fix this